# Automatic printing VB webbrowser

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB project with a webbrowser from the toolbox but when i am on a website and i have to print something there is a dialog. Can that dialog be disabled. I can't add code to the webpage because it is not hosted by me.

Greets,

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't disable this dialog. This is a security feature of your web browser (including the WebBrowser control, which relies on IE). It's there to prevent the kind of spam that shows up at fax machines.

Comment: Can i use a alternate than the standard webbrowser control? Because i know that chrome can print without confirmation.

Comment: No, Chrome won't print without confirmation. Chrome will show some other than the standard print dialog, but it won't print without confirmation. Again: this is a standard feature of browser design. It's a security feature, and so there won't be a work around.

Comment: It does. If you start chrome with the command --kiosk-printing

Comment: You could try this, but I doubt you'll have much luck: https://github.com/webkitdotnet/webkitdotnet